# Recover Internal Memory Data + Moto G

Tags: internal-storage, data-recovery, motorola-moto-g

Sad day for me, I copied some images to my phone from PC. When opened my gallery, not a single image could be seen. Everything wiped out suddenly. There were tons of photos (No backup).

My Moto G (1st Gen) is not even rooted, which makes it even more difficult to recover data.

Is there any way I can recover Lost/deleted data from Internal Memory?

Please someone help! I am in real trouble.

Comment: Hey Anuj, unfortunately there is no way to recover data if it has been already  deleted. If you used google photos they were most likely backed up to the cloud. Check thoroughly if there's anything left on your phone.

Comment: Please check with our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) and my [list of "undelete apps"](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872). Despite of what Devin wrote, you still might be lucky to recover your files.

Comment: @Izzy Can you please guide me?

Comment: @AnujMattóõ Not very far. As your device isn't rooted, we can't use "forensic methods" (which would be the safest, here: creating an image of the storage and carving that). I've never used any of those apps to restore data, so I cannot guide you with that – but they should be pretty straight-forward. Keep in mind: each and every write on the same storage where you want to recover data from increases the risk of that data being overwritten, so don't wait too long.